# Why is the Frank-Wolfe algorithm projection-free while gradient descent isn't?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, machine-learning, gradient-descent, projection

While reading [this article](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7236-on-frank-wolfe-and-equilibrium-computation.pdf) about the Frank-Wolfe algorithm, I did not understand why the Frank-Wolfe algorithm is projection-free, while the gradient descent is not. 
I think the problem is, that I do not understand what it means for an operation to be projection free.

Within linear algebra, I understand that a transformation is a projection if it is idempotent. 
I also understand that it is good to have projection-free algorithms (it makes it possible to reduce the complexity) - but I do not know why this is the case. Is it because the Frank-Wolfe uses a linear optimization oracle?

So my question is this: When is an operation projection-free, and why can the complexity of projection-free algorithms be reduced?

Comment: Look here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4657. Especially section 1.1. Projection works by ensuring that when we do our gradient descent or local search we keep in the feasible region. In section 1.1, we see cases where this project is very hard. Projection-free implementation, according to this paper at least, uses solves this using one linear optimization over the convex domain in Thm 1.1.

Comment: Thank you, the article really helped!